# Firebase Realtime database not updating data

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to Firebase and I am trying to learn its database.
This is what my code looks like.

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.example.roomdemo.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private  var binding: ActivityMainBinding? = null


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding?.root)

        binding?.button?.setOnClickListener {
            val rootNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            val reference = rootNode.getReference("Users")
            reference.setValue("hello")
        }

    }
}
```

I am simply trying to set the value 'hello' to my node 'Users'.
But Somehow it's not working.
Are there any configuration settings that I missed? Please help me.
Also pasting a screenshot of how the database looks like
[Database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzTPg.png)

Please help to connect my code with the database

This is how my rules looks like

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "true"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to attach a listener to the serValue() operation, to see if something went wrong?

Comment: @AlexMamo can you please tell me how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see if something goes wrong, you have to attach a listener and handle exceptions:

```
reference.setValue("hello").addOnCompleteListener {
    if (it.isSuccessful) {
        Log.d"(TAG", "Data added successfully.")
    } else {
        //Never ignore potential errors!
        Log.d("TAG", "Failed with: ${it.exception?.message}")
    }
}
```

If the above operation doesn't add anything to the database, it's most likely because the Firebase servers reject the operation due to improper security rules. So you have [set the proper rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security) in your Firebase console.

Comment: Funny. "Data added successfully. " is the result. And in database also value is coming now. I still didn't understand why is was not coming before. But I am happy that it worked. Thanks.

Comment: and now it stopped working again. nothing in log. This is so strange

Comment: If you encounter another problem, please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: No, its the similar problem. Few minutes back it was working absolutely fine. and now its stopped updating data to the database. i havent made any change to the code @AlexMamo

Comment: Check the security rules in Firebase Console.

Comment: this is how my rules looks like

Comment: The rules look good to me. Be also sure to have an internet connection on the device.

Comment: I am using android studio emulator . and internet is working perfectly fine in that

Comment: Okay I found the problem. So it not working when i connect my laptop with my wifi broadband. But it works fine when i am connecting my laptop to mobile data hotspot. Can you explain me why this is happening

Comment: Maybe there is something that stops the connection to Firebase servers when you're using the wifi broadband. But good to hear that it works now.